# How can I write a function boolean succeeds(char a, char b, String s)? using s.equals(""), s.charAt(0), s.substring(1)

Tags: java, string

I am trying to write a function that takes a string s and returns true if every occurrence of the character b is always succeeded by the character a, and false otherwise.
I have tried:

```
boolean succeeds(char a, char b, String s) {
    boolean to_return = true;
    boolean seen_a = false;
    while(true) {
        if (s.equals("")) return to_return;
            char c2 = s.charAt(0);
            if (c2 == a) seen_a = true;
            if (c2 == b) {
                if (!seen_a) return false;
            }
            s = s.substring(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I think I have the right idea. But I don't know how to put it together.

Comment: Do you mean that right after every `b` should be `a`?

Comment: You can just use a regular expression. See my answer below.

Comment: May we presume the question to be homework?

Comment: Only if we can also presume the question is one of those rare instances of *fun* homework. :) Come on, post an answer! Join our club of 7+ homework-doing chumps below.

Answer (score 7):

Given the guidelines, you can do something along the lines of

```
while (!s.equals("")) {
    char c = s.charAt(0);  // record first char
    s = s.substring(1);    // cut off first char


    // if "first char is 'b' and next is
    // not 'a'", we can return false
    if (c == b && (s.equals("") || s.charAt(0) != a))
        return false;                
}

return true;
```

---

By the way, this can be done much more easily:

```
return s.replace(""+b+a, "").indexOf(b) < 0;
```

(I just noticed that this approach was originally outlined in [@JosephMyers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111857/how-can-i-write-a-function-boolean-succeedschar-a-char-b-string-s-using-s-e/18111984#18111984))

Comment: Lol. I was about to comment - you didn't use `s.equals("")`, but just now you changed, and literally met all the requirement. +1

Comment: Note that this will create hell lot of new string objects, for a very long string.

Comment: This will blow up if there is a `b` at the last character.

Comment: @TedHopp Yes, you are right. I think it should work fine now.

Comment: Indeed it does. Nice save! A gold star for using only the allowed methods.

Comment: Your logic should say `if (c == b && (s.equals("") || s.charAt(0) != a)`

Comment: Your main answer has a problem with the string "b" (in the loop, c = "b", s = "", so therefore `c == b`, but `s.equals("")`, and your conditional `if (c == b && !s.equals("") && s.charAt(0) != a) return false;` fails, and the return value will be `true`). I suggested a fix.

Comment: @JosephMyers Yes, thanks for the tip. I took your suggestion with the `if` condition.

Comment: @arshajii so sorry! There is a missing closing parentheses in my conditional that I didn't notice when typing in the small comment box. Can you add it to your answer, because I can't edit my comment anymore??

Comment: @JosephMyers No problem, I added it in.

Comment: You're welcome, and definitely +1 for both your answers! It's funny that we all got so excited that now the OP has seven answers and plenty of code to play with!

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like homework, so it's probably your responsibility to work out the details, but several suggestions keep coming to my mind, anyway.

For instance, you could try:

1. Remove all occurrences of "ba" in a temporary string.
2. If no other letter(s) "b" remain in the temporary string, then return `true`.
3. Otherwise return `false`.

Hints: You can use the [`replace` method](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/java-string-replace-example-tutorial.html) in step 1 and [`indexOf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm) in step 2. (Click the links for tutorials/instructions You should be able to do this in two or three lines of code, depending on whether you use a ternary operator for the return value.)

Comment: Clever, slow, and out of bounds. `replace` and `indexOf` are not in the list of allowed methods for this assignment.

Answer (score 2):

It need not be so complex.  For example:

```
for (i = 0; i < s.length - 1; i++) {
  if (s.charAt(i - 1) == b && s.charAt(i) != a) {
    return false;
  }
}
return !s.endsWith(String.valueOf(b));
```

Comment: He can only use `charAt(0)`: *"using s.equals(“”), s.charAt(0), s.substring(1)"*.

Comment: `caba` would return false with your algo, but *every occurrence of the character b is always succeeded by the character a* in `caba`

Comment: The OP did not say that every occurrence of "a" needs to be preceded by "b," but that is what your answer checks.

Comment: Not fixed. OP can only use `charAt(0)` (not `charAt(i)`) and cannot use `endsWith` or `String.valueOf`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're limited to the functions you put in the title, and that you want to check if every b is followed by a (and not the other way around): you're halfway there, but your logic is a bit backwards.  When you're going through the string:

(1) When you see "b", you will need to remember that fact.  So you probably want a variable seen_b instead of seen_a.

(2) On the next character, if you remember that you just saw "b", you then need to make sure the next character is "a".  So instead of

```
if (c2 == b) {
    if (!seen_a) return false;
}
```

you probably should have something like

```
if (seen_b) {
    if (c2 != a) return false;
}
```

or more concisely

```
if (seen_b && c2 != a) return false;
```

(3) Since seen_b==true means that the *last* character you saw is b, make sure you set it back to false every time you see something that isn't b.

(4) Make sure you do things right when the last character of the string is b.  You have to return false because this isn't followed by "a".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I have not compiled this. Hopefully it gets you in the right direction, even with possible syntax errors.

```
public boolean succeeds(char a, char b, String s){
    boolean sawFirst= false;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(!sawA){
            if(s.charAt(i)==b)
                sawFirst = true;
        }
        else{
            if(s.charAt(i)!=a)
                return false;
            else sawFirst= false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: He can only use `charAt(0)`.

Comment: That's not in the question anywhere is it?

Comment: In the title it says *"using s.equals(“”), s.charAt(0), s.substring(1)"*.

Comment: Geez, I think you caught an obvious oversite of mine last night too didn't you? I need you in my life haha. Shoot.

Answer (score 0):

using s.equals(“”), s.charAt(0), s.substring(1) ?

how about this:

```
public static boolean succeeds(final char a, final char b, String s)
{
if(s==null||s.equals(""))
  return true;
char previousFirstChar,newFirstChar;
previousFirstChar=s.charAt(0);
while(true)
  {
  s=s.substring(1);
  if(s.equals(""))
     {
     if(previousFirstChar==b)
       return false;
     break;
     }
  newFirstChar=s.charAt(0);
  if(previousFirstChar==b && newFirstChar!=a))
    return false;
  previousFirstChar=newFirstChar;
  }
return true;
}
```

Comment: Fails if the last character is b.  Watch out for those boundary conditions!!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your title, I'm unclear if you mean you *have* to use s.equals, .charAt, and .substring. However, if not, you can use a regular expression `.*b[^a].*|.*b$` (thank you **ajb**) for this, where the function fails if it matches `b` followed by any character but `a` (or the special case `b` at the end of the string), e.g.:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 
...

public boolean succeeds (char a, char b, String s) {

    String quoteda = Pattern.quote(Character.toString(a));
    String quotedb = Pattern.quote(Character.toString(b));
    return !(s.matches(".*" + quotedb + "[^" + quoteda + "].*|.*" + quotedb + "$"));

}
```

Note that this will return true if the string doesn't contain `a` at all. If you want it to return false in that case, you'd have to check first:

```
public boolean succeeds (char a, char b, String s) {

    if (s.indexOf(b) == -1)
        return false;

    String quoteda = Pattern.quote(Character.toString(a));
    String quotedb = Pattern.quote(Character.toString(b));
    return !(s.matches(".*" + quotedb + "[^" + quoteda + "].*|.*" + quotedb + "$"));

}
```

The reason we use Pattern.quote is to allow it to handle characters with special meaning in regular expressions, e.g. ']'.

If you *can't* use regular expressions, a state-machine style approach will give you good results:

```
public boolean succeeds (char a, char b, String s) {

    int state = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < s.length(); ++ n) {
        if (state == 0) {
            if (s.charAt(n) == b)
                state = 1;
        } else if (state == 1) {
            if (s.charAt(n) == a)
                state = 0;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    return (state == 0);

}
```

Since there's only two states you could just use a boolean.

Comment: I think a and b might be reversed.  Anyway, if you got the order right, the pattern should be `s.matches(quotedb + "[^" + quoteda + "]|" + quotedb + "$")`.  Watch those boundary conditions!!

Comment: Right on both accounts. Editing post. Thanks.

Comment: I might actually delete this post. I don't think the regular expression is correct.

Comment: Oops, we both forgot that "matches" requires that the entire string match.  How about `s.matches(".*" + quotedb + "([^" + quoteda + "].*)?")`

Comment: Of course this is all moot if the OP has to use charAt, substring(1), and equals("").