# Need some help trying to understand this code

Tags: java

I have been asked to: write a function `boolean succeeds(char a, char b, String s)` that takes a string s and returns true
if every occurrence of the character b is always succeeded by the character a, and false otherwise.

I came across this:

```
while (!s.equals("")) {
    char c = s.charAt(0);  // record first char
    s = s.substring(1);    // cut off first char


    // if "first char is 'b' and next is
    // not 'a'", we can return false
    if (c == b && (s.equals("") || s.charAt(0) != a))
        return false;                
}

return true;
```

I cant quite get my head around it though? What does the `s.equals""` mean?

Comment: The name is quite self-explanatory. It checks that `s` is equal to `""`, the empty string.

Comment: Please read some tutorial about Java like http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-string-comparison

Comment: Aha, I knew this code looked familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111857/how-can-i-write-a-function-boolean-succeedschar-a-char-b-string-s-using-s-e

Comment: @ JB Nizet: that is actually what I am trying to do but finding it very hard on how to start. Hence why I am looking at different examples of code for it and trying to gain some understanding. Chill out mate.

Answer (score 1):

First occurance:

It is checking if `s` is NOT a blank `String`.

You can find information on the `!` operator [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) and on `equals()' [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!s.equals("")) {
```

This will simply repeat the following code until `s` is the empty string, `""`. Since a single character is cut off each iteration, this will keep cutting off characters until there are no more left.

```
(s.equals("") || s.charAt(0) != a)
```

The `s.equals("")` is used to check if `s` is an empty string. This is needed because if it **is** an empty string, then `s.charAt` will fail.

The `||` operator is short-circuiting, meaning that if the first expression is true, the second one doesn't get evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why a String uses `.equals()` instead of `==` you need to understand a little bit of how Java stores data. In Java, you can only compare two primitives (int, float, double) or two pointers with each other with `==`. A string is not a primitive type. If you store an int (or an other primitive type), it will store the data itself. If you store an object, it will store a pointer to a place where the object actually is. If you make a String object

```
String a = new String( "I am a String!" );
```

it returns a pointer to that string somewhere else in memory. Now we make another string with exactly the same text:

```
String b = new String( "I am a String!" );
```

it returns a pointer to a *different* location, because it is a *different* object (notice the `new` keyword). If you would compare `a == b`, it would return false. Why? Because `a` is not the same String object as `b`. It's pointer is different. If you would do

```
String c = b;
```

`c` would point to the same String object as `b`. If you would compare them (`b == c`) it would return true.

To be able to compare their content, the String object has a `.equals()` method. It returns true when the content `a` is equal to `b` in `a.equals( b )`.

---

To get back to this problem. `s.equals("")` will create a new String with no content. For the reasoning above, if it would check `s == ""` it would always return false.

Comment: Lovellllllllllllllllllllly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In java when you see "" with nothing in the quotations it means that the value of that object is empty.

So the program will only run if there is some value (characters) in the string.

!= means not equal to. ! means not.

This is stop it running when someone hasn't entered a value.

So it says

while the value of String S ins't equal to nothing the program will run.